# on.message () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given (discord.py bot)

Tags: python, discord

So I have this simple discord bot written in python and when I try some commands, it gives me "on.message () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given". Here's the code of the bot.

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
from keep_alive import keep_alive


client = discord.Client ()



@client.event
async def on_ready () :
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Sivo nebo'))
  print ('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message () :
  if message.author == client.user :
    return  

  
  if message.content.startswith('!hi') :
    await message.channel.send('Hi!')
  if message.content.startswith('!goodbye') :
    await message.channel.send('Goodbye!')
  
    

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All events take an implicit context argument.

```
async def on_ready(ctx):
    ...

async def on_message(ctx):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `async def on_message(message):`

I'm quite sure that your current code won't work because message is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the [`discord.py` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you'll see that the [`on_message()` event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) implicitly takes on argument: `message`. So when you define `on_message` with not parameters, `discord.py` attempts to pass `message`, but is not able to.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return  

    if message.content.startswith('!hi') :
        await message.channel.send('Hi!')
    if message.content.startswith('!goodbye') :
        await message.channel.send('Goodbye!')
```

On a side note, I would recommend checking out the [`discord.ext.commands` framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), which allows you to create commands and is better than using `message.content.startswith()` and variations of that.